# Woocommerce: Show lowest price (instead of a range) for variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I am using *"[Replace the Variable Price range by the chosen variation price in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912300/replace-the-variable-price-range-by-the-chosen-variation-price-in-woocommerce-3/44914240#44914240)"* answer code and I have successfully removed the price range on the single product page. The price is now showing as "From: $x" which is exactly what I wanted.

[Single Product Page]

However, in the product category page, it is still showing as a price range (i.e., "HK$x – HK$x").  Would someone be able to advise?

[Category Page]

Comment: You will just need to replace the text prefix "Prices starting at" by "From:" in the code.

Comment: Sorry but I do not fully follow.  Where is the "Prices starting at" prefix in the code?

Comment: In here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54698434/replace-woocommerce-variable-products-price-range-with-the-min-price/54702815#54702815

Comment: It works!  However, it is showing the sale price (i.e., after discount) only.  I want it to show exactly like a simple product where the regular price will be crossed out and show the discount price.

Comment: Thanks,  Your code will now show the original price.  But what I wanted is show a crossed-out original price and then the discounted price on its right.  Is that possible?