# WooCommerce Price Display Prefix?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have added the following code to my functions.php

```
function iconic_format_price_range( $price, $from, $to ) {

    return sprintf( '%s: %s', __( 'From', 'iconic' ), wc_price( $from ) );
} 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_price_range', 'iconic_format_price_range', 10, 3 );
```

This displays a 'from:' on my variable products.

When products are on sale (both variable and single products), I want this to change to '**Now From**' for variable products and '**Now**' for Single products, whilst displaying the old prices crossed out [price del].

How could this be done?

Comment: Take a look at this, because it contains a large part of the answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008490/replace-woocommerce-variable-products-price-range-with-up-to-and-the-max-price 
If you can't figure it out, do not hesitate to adjust your question 
on what you get stuck. Regards

Comment: Hello, thank you for the link. I've tried that code and tweaked the 'max' values to suit my 'min' values but it still doesn't do what I'd like.

With [Simple Products]https://imgur.com/OukgC0o, I'd like it to display 'WAS $$, NOW $$' with the now price in red & uppercase

With [Variable Products] https://imgur.com/I5gpJnj I want it to display 'WAS $$, NOW FROM $$' with the now price in red & uppercase